# Single Object Map or separate (large sizes)

Tags: java, performance, libgdx, hashmap

I'm using libGDX and theres a class [Pools](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.html) that holds an [ObjectMap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/ObjectMap.html) with [Pool](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Pool.html)(s).

Is it better to create seperate `ObjectMap`s for *effects* / *projectiles* or use the `Pools` class (simple way).

Won't a large `ObjectMap` slow down `get(Class)` method or is the performance lose acceptable?

Java Doc:

> /** An unordered map. This implementation is a cuckoo hash map using 3
>   hashes, random walking, and a small stash for problematic  * keys.
>   Null keys are not allowed. Null values are allowed. No allocation is
>   done except when growing the table size. 
>   * 
>   * This map
>   performs very fast get, containsKey, and remove (typically O(1), worst
>   case O(log(n))). Put may be a bit slower,  * depending on hash
>   collisions. Load factors greater than 0.91 greatly increase the
>   chances the map will have to rehash to the  * next higher POT size.  *
>   @author Nathan Sweet */

Comment: If you have millions of entries it would slow down a bit, but you are more likely to run out of memory first. I suggest you profile your application before considering all the things which might slow down your application because guessing is almost always wrong even if you have specialised in Java performance tuning for more than ten years.

Comment: There is a rat in separate.

Comment: If you have so many data classes that looking up their keys is taking too much time, that indicates a more serious design issue.

Comment: ObjectMap has constant time lookup (essentially). A map with many entries does not take longer than a map with few entries to look up the value for a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are better off sticking with the `Pools` class. I think you are misunderstanding how this class works. The `Pools` class stores an `ObjectMap`, which stores pools of objects by their class type.

For example, if you do `Pools.obtain(Bullet.class)`, the class will find a `Bullet` pool, and create an object from there. The same will happen with any other class you might have. This means that you are really only having a few pools, in one objectmap.

Unless you have thousands or millions of data different data types, using this class is perfectly fine.